# let $K_n=\Big\{z\in G: d(z, G^c)\geq\frac{1}{n}\Big\}$ is$K_n$ non empty for some $n$??

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

let $G$ be  open  set in $\mathbb{C}$.$\ $ let $K_n=\Big\{z\in G:d(z,G^c)\geq\frac{1}{n}\Big\}$

then ofcourse $K_n$ is subset of $G$. and $K_n\subset K_{n+1}.$ my question is $K_n$ non empty for some $n$??

Comment: yes $K_n$ is non empty as long as G is open

Comment: @Guy Fsone please explain why is that

Comment: let $z_0\in G$ then $d(z_0,\mathbb{C}/G)>0.$ then choosing $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<$$d(z_0,\mathbb{C}/G)$. then $z_0\in K_n$. is it wright ??

Comment: that is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that one has the following:

> **Proposition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a topological metric space and $A$ be a subset of $X$, then one has:
>   $$\forall x\in X,d(x,A)=0\iff x\in\overline{A}.$$

**Proof.** Let us proceed by double implication.

- Assume that $d(x,A)=0$, then by definition of the greatest lower bound, one has:
  $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 1},\exists a_n\in A\textrm{ s.t. }d(x,a_n)\leqslant\frac{1}{n}.$$
  Therefore, $a_n\to x$ and $x\in\overline{A}$.
- Assume that $x\in\overline{A}$, then there exists $(a_n)_n\in A^\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\to x$. Besides, one has:
  $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},d(x,A)\leqslant d(x,a_n).$$
  Taking the limit as $n\to+\infty$ leads to $d(x,A)=0$.

Whence the result. $\Box$

In your case, $\mathbb{C}\setminus G$ is closed, since $G$ is open, hence:
$$d(z,\mathbb{C}\setminus G)=0\iff z\not\in G.$$
In particular, for $z\in G$, $d(z,\mathbb{C}\setminus G)>0$ and is greater than $1/n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Metric space. Not topological

Comment: @ZachTeitler Was about to fix it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in G $ we have $dist(z,G^c)>0$ that is there exists $n_0$ such that, $$dist(z,G^c)>\frac{1}{n_0} $$ that is z\in K_{n_0}. Therefore for ever $n\ge n_0$, $z\in K_n$. That is $K_n\neq \emptyset$ for all $n\ge n_0$ which is enough to prove what want after all 
$$G= \bigcup_{n\ge n_0}K_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is not empty, let $z\in G$. If $G\neq \mathbb{C}$ then $$d(z,\mathbb{C}\backslash G)=\inf_{x\in \mathbb{C}\backslash G}d(z,x)<\infty$$
is a positive number. To see this, remember that since $G$ is open there exists a circle $B_{\varepsilon}(z)\subset G$ centered in $z$ with positive radius $\varepsilon>0$. This implies $d(z,\mathbb{C}\backslash G)\geq \varepsilon$. There exists a number $N(\varepsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\leq \varepsilon$ and thus $$z\in K_{N(\varepsilon)}\subset K_{N(\varepsilon)+1}\subset ...$$.
So in this case all but a finite number of the sets $K_n$ are non-empty.
If $G=\mathbb{C}$ You have $K_n=\mathbb{C}$ for all $n$. Just in the trivial case $G=\emptyset$ all $K_n$ are empty.